# Why logic-less template systems uses double brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, mustache, liquid

Noticed that mostly all logic-less templates systems (Mustache, Handlebars, Liquid) uses double brackets for tags i.e.

`{{tag}}`

Is there any reason why they use double brackets instead of single ones? Why not simply use something like this.

`{tag}`

Are there any implications in using single brackets for tags in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Might the reason be that {{ and }} are very very more unlikely to appear in the text of the template than the single versoins?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same reasons why you "protect" quotes or double quotes in a string. You have to find a way to permit people to put { and } characters in their strings. The {} braces symbols doubling syntax is clear compared to that one that would use different symbols as \{ or \}.

Let's do a comparison with the braces doubled :

```
 This is a template and here is what has to be changed {{variable}}
 Now I can also still use my braces { } without having to protect them
```

And the example with for example \{

```
 This is a template and here is what has to be changed \{variable\}
 Now I can also still use my braces { } without having to protect them
```

Honestly what would you choose